# Host multipe sites on nginx

Tags: nginx, cname

Currently my nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
  listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
  listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  #
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  # Attempt to load static files, if not found route to @rootfiles
  location ~ (.+)\.(html|json|txt|js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
    try_files $uri @rootfiles;
  }

  # deny access to . files, for security
  #
  location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
  }

  location @rootfiles {
     rewrite ^/(?:triangles|equation-of-a-line)/(.*) /$1 redirect;
  }

  sendfile off;
}
```

I basically have one site at `root /usr/share/nginx/html;`.

How can I change this to allow multiple sites with each site hosted at the same root directory?

Also, I have cname * mapped to the IP address.

How can I change this so that each website has its own cname?

Comment: To answer on your deleted Haskell question: you need to fix your `resolver: …` value in your project-specific stack.yaml.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You edit that file, check which LTS version is compatible with 7.10.x, and you're done. However, if you still encounter that problem, why did you delete your question in the first place?

Comment: running stack upgrade and then stack setup seemed to cure everything